# Mineral B vs carbon steel frying pans

Tags: cookware

I am looking to buy a frying pan but the material has confused me.

One is said to be Mineral B, the other is carbon steel. I was confused about the differences between the 2 materials. Thankfully, I wasn't alone and found https://www.chowhound.com/post/confused-de-buyer-mineral-element-pan-iron-steel-greatly-834744 which goes into detail about what materials exist within iron / steel etc

If it helps, the 2 products I'm looking at are https://www.debuyer.com/en/products/carbone-plus-round-frying-pan-stainless-steel-cold-handle and https://www.debuyer.com/en/products/mineral-b-round-fry-pan

What I can't tell is, if there is going to be any difference when cooking and caring for the 2 frying pans.

I am not asking for a recommendation. I'm only interested in what one could expect to cook using the materials (and if the difference of the material really is going to make a difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Mineral B" and "Carbone Plus" are two brands of carbon steel cookware manufactured by De Buyer. The main difference between the two is the shape of the handle, and the secondary handle on the larger "Mineral B" pans. "Mineral B" additionally comes from the factory with a thin coat of beeswax, but that isn't going to make a significant difference after seasoning.

If you want to get one of those, pick based on the handle.